# Why can't Jackson deserialize this JSON?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm using Jackson to parse an ElasticSearch document into following data class

```kotlin
data class ElasticCity(
    val id: Long,
    val regionId: Long,
    val countryIso: String,
    val isFeatured: Boolean?
) {
    // For now Jackson does not support this for constructor parameters https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/562
    @JsonAnySetter
    val names: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
}
```

However I'm getting following error (formatting mine)

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException:
    Instantiation of [simple type, class net.goout.locations.model.ElasticCity] value failed
    for JSON property country_iso due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter countryIso which is a non-nullable type
    at [Source: (byte[])
        "{
            "name.cs":"Brno",
            "countryIso":"CZ",
            "regionId":85682423,
            "timezone":"Europe/Prague",
            "name.de":"Brünn",
            "name.sk":"Brno",
            "id":101748109,
            "isFeatured":true,
            "name.pl":"Brno",
            "name.en":"Brno"
        }";
    line: 1, column: 186] (through reference chain: net.goout.locations.model.ElasticCity["country_iso"])
```

Clearly the key `countryIso` is present in the JSON but for some reason Jackson complains a key `country_iso` is missing. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: As per error it should not be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

```
data class ElasticCity(
    val id: Long,
    val regionId: Long,
    @JsonProperty(value = "countryIso") val countryIso: String,
    val isFeatured: Boolean?
)
```

Jackson mapper implicitly converts non start caps characters _

If you want to fix this at multiple places then take a look at 
`@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy..`
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy

Comment: really, if that was the problem then how about other variables getting recognized? By default naming scheme is camel case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you also know since what version Jackson does this? And if it is possible to turn it off for all fields? Otherwise I'd have to annotate majority of my fields.

Comment: updated the ans to include JSON naming strategy for all fields @Jen

Comment: @QuickSilver Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The library I'm using overrides the default strategy to `CAMEL_CASE`.

@ani

Comment: glad to hear @Jen